# Chrome extension background message listener fires up twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, listener

I got an chrome extension that works like this:

Background every few seconds checks site x for changes, if they occur background opens new tab with page Y and does some page automation (fills survey in ajax - based page). Page automation is done by content script. Content script needs to ask Background for permission to start working. It does that by sending message and waiting for reply. When content script finishes it's job it sends message to Background with information about success or not. When failure tab should be updated with new link, when succes - tab should be closed. The problem is, sometimes - not always, bacground get's messages twice. Once - when tab fails it's job, and second time just after tab is updated with new link. I wish i could know why...

Here is script:

Background.js listener creation

```
function create_listerner(){
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            switch(request.greeting){
                case "site_opened":
                    if (sender.tab.id == tabId) {
                        sendResponse({
                            farewell : "go"
                        });
                    } else {
                        sendResponse({
                            farewell : "stop"
                        });
                    }
                    break;
                case "imDoneWithSuccess":
                    //update tab logic
                    break;
                case "imDoneWithFail":
                    //close tab logic
                    actNgo(url,arr);
                    break;
            }
        });
}
```

Listener call is made once, when user starts script from context menu: background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title : "Start",
    contexts : ["browser_action"],
    onclick : function () {
        create_listerner();
    }
});
```

tab update looks simple: background.js

```
function actNgo(url,arr){
    chrome.storage.local.set({
        array : arr,
        ndz : 1
    }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.update(
            tabId,
            {
                "url" : url,
                "active" : false
            }, function (tab) {
                console.log("tabId "+tabId);
            });
    });
}
```

content script is injected into website, site doesn't reload as is ajax based, and even if - messages cannot be send without proper conditions met

content.js

```
function SR(st) {
    var status ;
    if(st){
        status = "imDoneWithSuccess";
    } else {
        status = "imDoneWithFail";
    }
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        greeting : status 
    }, function (response) {
    });
}
```

content script should work only on tabs that bacground.js opens

```
function askForPermission() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        greeting : "site_opened"
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.farewell == 'go') {
            start();
        } else {
            console.log("bad tab");
        }
    });
}
```

again - there is no possibility for them to fire up by themselves.

Log file looks like this:

```
Background: tab created;
content script: askForPermission(); <-sends message asking for permission to start
Bacground: go <- allows. 
content script: (content script logs, working as intended)
Background listener: imDoneWithFail;
Background update tab;
background listener: imDoneWithFail; <- shouldn't happen, doesn't look like it conten't script even started to work as it didn't ask for permission. Looks like listener is fired up twice...
Background update tab;
content script: askForPermission(); <-sends message asking for permission to start
Bacground: go <- allows.
```

edit: manifest

```
{
  "name": "Test script",
  "version": "0.0.78",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["src/background/background.js"]
    },
  "icons": {
    "19": "icons/icon19.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "src/options/index.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "Test",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://localhost/survey/*",
    "storage",
    "contextMenus",
      "tabs",
      "webRequest"
  ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
        "http://localhost/survey/*",
        "https://localhost/survey/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/jquery/jquery.min.js",
        "src/inject/content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Before someone ask - I tried to use long-live connections, but i had same issue. Why does it happen?

Comment: Maybe your content script is injected into all frames. Can you edit the question and add manifest.json? BTW you add the listener every time the extension toolbar icon is clicked although, supposedly, Chrome ignores subsequent invocations because the callback is identical.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just updated question with manifest, I know that if i will start script few times more listeners will be added, but i don't do that, so it's something else... Can every frame send own message back to background? Content script code is fired only once according to log file.

Comment: Well, I'd set the breakpoints at all lines that send and receive the messages both in content and background scripts. Can you do it? Or upload the extension somewhere and link it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a answer, the problem is with function changing url of tab.

```
function actNgo(url,arr){
    chrome.storage.local.set({
        array : arr,
        ndz : 1
    }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.update(
            tabId,
            {
                "url" : url,
                "active" : false
            }, function (tab) {
                console.log("tabId "+tabId);
            });
    });
}
```

Function, when given same url as current didn't refreshed tab, and content script couldn't fire up as new...  Still don't know why listener fired up messages twice, but since my change it has stopped.

I don't know if this fix will help anyone, but i fixed this by first changing tab url to blank, and then to new one.

```
    chrome.tabs.update(
        tabId,
        {
            "url" : "about:blank",
            "active" : false
        }, function (tab) {
            console.log("bcgr: aktualizujStroneIObstaw: pusta: tabId "+tabId);
            chrome.tabs.update(
                tabId,
                {
                    "url" : url_beta,
                    "active" : false
                }, function (tab) {
                    console.log("bcgr: aktualizujStroneIObstaw: wlasciwa: tabId "+tabId);

                }
              );
```